# 22.04.1, get 'newer' nginx official package?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, nginx

Upgraded to 22.04.1 (from 20.04) on a server having **nginx** 1.18.0 default package. nginx serves a few websites secured with wildcard certificates.

And I get this error (a lot, which does not seem to interfere with the clients activity)

```
SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while keepalive
```

It seems it comes from a bug in openssl 3.0.2 and (or) nginx 1.18.0.

The best solution I found online is to upgrade to a newer nginx (1.22). However that package is not "official", it comes from another 3rd party source. But I'd prefer to keep using official packages.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to know if Canonical / Ubuntu intend to release a newer version (at least 1.19), and when?
- Or are they only releasing security fixes, like 1.18.0a, not bug fixes?
- And we are condemned to use 1.18 until 24.04? (or use a 3rd party source)

Comment: Never, mostly yes, and yes. Although they might backport non-security bug fixes if the bugs are problematic enough.

Comment: Without an actual bug report to track, the question seems hypothetical...and unanswerable: Some bugs get fixed before the next release of Ubuntu (by patching, NOT by bumping to a higher version), others don't. Depends upon the severity of the bug and the availability of volunteers to do the patching and testing.